# How to test concurrent modification in robolectric 3.2

Tags: android, multithreading, robolectric

I'm trying to create a test in Robolectric where two threads write some lines to the same file. Now, the problem is not to ensure that the operation is thread-safe but how to make a test that fails and result in a concurrent modification of the file in robolectric.

Does Robolectric even have a way to handle concurrency? Attempt to use

```
ShadowApplication.runBackgroundTasks();
```

Did not work the way I hoped, doing the tasks serially (as documented in its code) preventing it from actually encountering a concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to deal with multithreading, especially is you want to simulate some scenario in the tests.

I'm trying to build to make architecture where tasks creation and tasks running are separated. As example:

```
public class LoginRunnable extends Runnable {
   public LoginRunnable(@NonNull SomeNetwork network, @NonNull LoginInfo loginInfo) {
      this.network = network;
      this.loginInfo = loginInfo;
   }

   public void run() {
      session = network.login(loginInfo);
   }

   public Session getSession(){}
}

//somewhere
ExecutorService networkExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

//somwhere else
SomeNetowrk network = new SomeNetwork(...);

//somewhere else
netowrkExecutor.execute(new LoginRunnable(network, new LoginInfo(...)));
```

With this approach, you can easily mock dependencies on every level and test functionality. You could also mix the order of running actions to simulate different behaviour is you have them running simultaneously in production code. That should cover around 95% such cases. And rest 5% you should design your system that it is robust for concurrent modifications from different threads.

With this approach you also don't need any Robolecric in your tests (most probably).

You have to write much less boilerplate code and classes with java8 and RxJava.

Hope it helps!